# how to get Kmeans cluster data with Spark Kmeans model

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

I'm using Spark ML to do Kmeans clustering on 6 Million records, I used the following code to get the Kmeans modle:

```scala
val model = KMeans.train(parsedData, 3, 8)
```

I set the cluster center number is 3. With the following code I can get the 3 cluster centers via the following code:

```scala
model.clusterCenters.foreach{println}
```

My question is that how can I get the real group data, I suppose Spark should output 6 Million real data with 3 groups.

**Further question please**: The above task for clustering text documents. So I transferred the text documents to float vectors. Spark only out put the float vectors, but I wanna get the original text document directly, any ideas please? 
For example:
My documents as following:

```scala
doc1: {the book is good}
doc2: {the weather is sunny}
doc3: {rain is coming}
```

I transferred the above text file to float vectors as following for feeding Spark ML:

```scala
doc1:{0.2,0.3,0.5,1.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}
doc1:{0.2,0.0,0.5,0.0,0.8,0.0,0.0,0.0}
doc1:{0.0,0.3,0.0,0.0,0.8,0.0,0.0,0.9}
```

So I hope Spark can directly output the clustered original text docs rather float vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `map` and `predict`:

```
parsedData.map(p => (model.predict(p), p))
```

To get to original documents you can try `zip` method as long as data hasn't been reordered (shuffled) otherwise:

```
model.predict(parsedData).zip(rawDocuments)
```